# Problem with CIVICRM Notes (CSS?)

Tags: civicrm-home, css, contact-view

I have a (new) installation with civiCRM 4.7.2 (Joomla 3.4.8) regarding the display size of the "Notes". For my template I know where to find the style information, however I have difficulties to locate the layout for the back-end and front-end notes of civiCRM.

As you can see the back-end detailed view of notes has some layout problems. The text gets extremely unreadable using the default settings. It would be far better for usability to have a wider text field. See below:

[image: front-end Notes view]

Somehow interrelated could be the narrow default field size if notes is displayed in the front end. "Your Request" is actually the notes field. Yes there is the pull handle (red) to re-size the imput field, but most users are missing it! So is there a way to re-size the default (orange) width for this as well -- and might it be the same value?

[image: front-end Notes view]

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

B ert